# Update State/Context to redirect to protected route react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-state-management

I am new to react and am trying to update the state/context of a component from a child component.

From the AuthProvider() below I can access the user state across the entire application.

If user is null, I am shown an auth page. Here I can login and call `loginUser()` which logs a user in on the server and returns with a refresh and access token and a username... stores the token in local storage and returns a user. Here is that function...

auth-provider.js

```
export function handleUserResponse(user) {

  window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, user.refresh_token)
  return user

}

function login({email, password}) {

    return client('/login', {email, password}).then(handleUserResponse)
//the client() function accepts an endpoint and user login info. 
}
```

I am trying to update the state in AuthProvider.js from the login function which is called from a login page, so that I am redirected to the protected page once I the token is received. I need to set the `user` to the new updated user. I am new to react and know this is a common scenario, but if anyone has encountered this before I more than appreciate any help.

So far... I have only been able to access the user variable and not change it from the login page.

AuthProvider.js

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();
  
export const getUser = () => auth.getToken().then((user) => ({ username:user}));
export const loginUser = (data) => auth.login(data).then((user) => ({ username:user }));


function AuthProvider({ children }) {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    status: "pending",
    error: null,
    user: null,
    token: null,
  });


  React.useEffect(() => {
    getUser().then(
      (user) => setState({ status: "success", error: null, user }),
      (error) => setState({ status: "error", error, user: null })
    );
  }, []);


  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={state}>
      {state.status === "pending" ? (
        "Loading..."
      ) : state.status === "error" ? (
        <div>
          Oh no
          <div>
            <pre>{state.error.message}</pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default { AuthProvider, AuthContext };
```

Home.js --where either the authenticated or unathenticated version of the app is rendered

```
import useAuthState from '../UseAuthState'

function Home() {
  const { user } = useAuthState();

  return user.username ? <AuthenticatedApp /> : <UnauthenticatedApp />;

}
export default Home;
```

UseAuthState.js   --this returns state data

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthContext from './AuthProvider'

function useAuthState() {

  const state = React.useContext(AuthContext.AuthContext);
  const isPending = state.status === "pending";
  const isError = state.status === "error";
  const isSuccess = state.status === "success";
  const isAuthenticated = state.user && isSuccess;
  return {
    ...state,
    isPending,
    isError,
    isSuccess,
    isAuthenticated,
  };
}
export default useAuthState;
```

Comment: So from what I can tell from your snippets, `AuthProvider` never calls `loginUser` to update anything. I think you also may not want the `useEffect` to run only once, but TBH your app flow is a little convoluted. Looks like one or both of `getUser`|`loginUser` *should* update state, but they don't.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt post the code but I call loginUser from a login page on buttonSubmit

Comment: Would I need to make another useEffect() hook for loginUser?

Comment: I'm not sure. It isn't clear what purpose the effects are serving. You should be able to update *some* auth state *somewhere* (probably the `state` in `AuthProvider`) and react will rerender and provide the updated `value={state}`.

Comment: exactly. I am just confused on how to update the state in AuthProvider from the login page.

Comment: right now I am calling the loginUser() function, but its not updating the state in AuthProvider because I dont know how to do that...yet :)

Comment: Generally speaking, when using the Context API you pass as the context value *some* "value" and functions to update *that* value. A simple example using a `useState` hook (`const [auth, setAuth] = useState({})` might be `<AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>...` where hopefully it is clear how the function to update state is passed.

Comment: i am getting an infinite loop when using setAuth in the child function

Comment: This *usually* happens when you invoke a state update function every render without any conditional check. Can you update your question with the new relevant code, the hook usage and child component? If possible, could you also try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue? It doesn't have to be all of your code, but just enough to reproduce it. If your project is hosted in github you can import the repo.